# Configure Google Compute Engine VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, google-compute-engine

I made an application with OpenCV using c ++ on debian 10in my PC. This app uses cpu and gpu to recognize objects and a local database to store data and images on the local disk. Now, I want to migrate a GCP.

Which of the GCP Compute Engine VM instance should I use to make my app work in the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [add a GPU to your VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#create-new-gpu-instance) when creating one ([you have several to choose from](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#gpus-list) depending on the region your instaince will be in) or you can add it later.

Also you mentioned a database - depending on how much performance you need you have to decide [what kind of disk you need (standard vs ssd)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks). Also - if your DB is very IOPS sensitive keep in mind that it [changes with disk size.](https://serverfault.com/a/994575/545593)